# Html not reading fonts

Tags: html, css, fonts, sass, font-face

I got fonts for my project. Museo Sans with 5 different weights. I need to use @font-face and use them in my website.

```
@font-face {
font-family: "Museo Sans 100";
src: url('/app/fonts/museosans-100-webfont.ttf') format('opentype');
font-weight: 100;
}
@font-face {
font-family: "Museo Sans 300";
src: url('/app/fonts/museosans-300-webfont.ttf') format('opentype');
font-weight: 300;
}

@font-face {
font-family: "Museo Sans 500";
src: url('/app/fonts/museosans-500-webfont.ttf') format('opentype');
font-weight: 500;
}
@font-face {
font-family: "Museo Sans 700";
src: url('/app/fonts/museosans-700-webfont.ttf') format('opentype');
font-weight: 700;
}
@font-face {
font-family: "Museo Sans 900";
src: url('/app/fonts/museosans-900-webfont.ttf') format('opentype');
font-weight: 900;
}


//Font Variables
//-----
$font: 'Museo Sans 100';


@import '../utilities/fonts';

 html {
 font-family: $font;
  }

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1644px;
  padding: 0 14.024390243%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

When i call it in my scss , i can see it when i inspect my html but the font stays the same.. nothing happens. Any opinions?
P.S. the fonts i got are all ttf .

This is the error I'm getting:

`museosans-100-webfont.ttf:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

Comment: Check if the browser console has anything to say in that regard first of all.

Comment: museosans-100-webfont.ttf:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: This might be because the browser didn't support the type. You maybe will find the answer if you refer here https://www.balbooa.com/knowledgebase/32-documentation-faq-joomla/176-how-to-add-custom-font-to-website-through-fontface.

Comment: here you will find what you need https://www.onlinewebfonts.com/download/cf2e520b1f09b1054a329a50e225ac01

Comment: So it looks like you simply specified the path wrong … is that `app` directory really available via `http://foo.tld/app/`?

Comment: The format of .ttf is (truetype) and not (opentype)

Comment: Ah yes the path was wrong .. Thanks for the clue ! :)

Comment: best way to go with web font generator  [see](https://transfonter.org) upload your ttf file